# VB.NET: Process.HasExited with browser as default pdf-reader

Tags: vb.net, pdf, process

I am currently working on a Tool which is able to receive a Pdf-File from a web service. I can open this PDF with Adobe-Acrobat Reader DC which is my 
default PDF reader and save it somewhere.

Usually the workflow should be: GetPDF -> Open PDF -> (when closed) -> ask user if he want it to be saved

This does work when I use Adobe-Acrobat Reader DC. When i change my default 
PDF reader to any browser.

then the workflow does look like: GetPDF -> Open PDF and ask user to save the file

This does only happen when the browser is already open and the Pdf opens in a new Tab.

So the Problem is the Process.HasExited Method which iam using to wait until the user is ready for the userinteraction(Savefiledialog).

Does anybody have a suggestion for a good workaround or do i make something horribly wrong?

Here is the relevant Code:

```
Try
    Dim Proc As New Process
    Proc.StartInfo.FileName = dateipfad
    Proc.Start()
    While Not Proc.HasExited
        Application.DoEvents()
    End While
    pdfOK = True
```

Comment: Firstly, that's bad code whether it works or not.  What you have there is known as a "busy wait" loop and it is the worst construct in all of programming.  NEVER do that.  What you should be doing is handling the `Exited` event of the process.

Comment: As for the question, there's not much you can do if you're going to let the user use any PDF reader because there would not be any way to handle them all.  Even some dedicated PDF readers might use a tabbed UI and wouldn't create a dedicated process per file and to be able to detect closure of tabs in every possible app would be impossible.

Comment: You might be best to open the file in a form of your own, which you can know for sure has closed when it closes.